# application Error net::err_proxy_connection_faild (http://192.168.43.162)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I create a mobile application, I try to execute it on my phone, the compilation is going well, but arriving at the time of launching here is the result that it turns over to me
[image]

then I follow a can block, if some can guide me